# Ant copy directory if file found in directory

Tags: ant

I've been using simple copy to grab a paticular file out of a directory:

```
<copy todir="target/failures">
    <fileset dir="target/reports" includes="**/*FAILED.txt"/>
</copy>
```

Now instead I'd like to copy the entire folder that contains this file to the failures folder. 
The directory structure looks like this:

```
target
    reports
        folder1
        folder2
        folder3
    failures
```

So if a failure is found in folder1, i want to copy the entire contents to failures and then continue on through the remaining folders.  It seems like it should be simple but I can't seem to find a built in task to accomplish this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) to decide if the copy target is executed.

```
<project name="demo" default="copy">

    <fileset id="failures" dir="target/reports" includes="**/*FAILED.txt"/>

    <condition property="failures.found">
        <resourcecount refid="failures" when="greater" count="0" />
    </condition>

    <target name="copy" if="failures.found">
        <copy todir="target/failures" overwrite="true">
            <fileset id="failures" dir="target/reports"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

</project>
```

## Update

A more capable and flexible solution uses the [groovy ANT task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task):

```
<project name="demo" default="copy">

    <path id="build.path">
        <pathelement location="/path/to/task/jars/groovy-all-2.1.1.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="copy">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <fileset id="failures" dir="target/reports" includes="**/*FAILED.txt"/>

        <groovy>
            project.references.failures.each {
                def failFile   = new File(it.toString())
                def failFolder = new File(failFile.parent)

                ant.copy(todir:"target/failures/${failFolder.name}", overwrite:true) {
                    fileset(dir:failFolder)
                }
            }
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: this will copy everything, i've added info for my structure in the question. Gives me a place to start, considering writing some code to handle it in an existing utility...

Comment: @SteveMiskiewicz I've updated my answer with an embedded groovy script